# Prevent users from uploading directly to SharePoint Document Library but allow uploading via Power App

Tags: powerapp, sp-online

We require specific metadata to accompany documents uploaded to a document library. To accomplish this we have a Power App with pull-down menus for various metadata entries.

Each document type has different metadata field entries. I.E. Some may have metadata for a specific field. Others may not. The Power App forces users to make a selection in each pull-down presented. Some selections display additional pull-down menus for more metadata.

All menus must have a selection before the user is presented with the upload file button. However, users may bypass all of this by going directly to the document library to upload a file. How may we prevent users from bypassing the Power App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir:

It is clear that you need to remove the default “Upload” button from the interface, which I have been asked to do in previous projects.
Since you referenced PowerApps forms, I assume that your tenant is running on SharePoint Online and the site is using the Modern UX.

You need to code a *List View Command Set* extension using SPFx ([see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api) and [this is a broader resource for SPFx too](https://github.com/orgs/SharePoint/repositories)) then deploy it from either your site collection’s app catalog or tenant’s app catalog.

***Please mark this response as an answer if it answered your question***